# How to implement ViewPagers with Dot Sliders in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am learning Xamarin.Android recently, I was trying to implement pageviewers with dot sliders for my practice from the last few days but failed to implement it, I had refereed many solutions from popular hubs like stackoverflow and github but failed to do so.
Can any one please explain me how to implement the viewpagers with dot sliders in xamarin.android.
I am attaching a photo to this for your reference, which would give you a clear view on my requirement.[image]

as you can see he is sliding the pages using the dot sliders i was trying to do so.
Please explain me how to do it in Xamarin.Android (Native)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this the sample project 'Android-ViewPagerIndicator to Xamarin.Android'. You need to include the library, where there are multiple implementation to display the indicators on viewpager.

https://github.com/Cheesebaron/ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: I had tried using this but had a problem while installing nugget packages (hope it is the library you are talking about) can you please help me with nugget packages which nugget package to install and so....

Comment: I have updated the source link. In this look at the implementation sample. You need to include the Library not LibraryV4 in your solution, and access by including the namespace "using DK.Ostebaronen.Droid.ViewPagerIndicator;"

Comment: You can use the below code to directly implement the dot indicators to your app

Comment: When i am implementing the dot indicators in the dashboard of my app it is not allowing me to navigate to another page, i am not facing this issue while debugging, when i remove from debugging i am facing this issue. this issue is generated when binding the circle page indicators, can you help me with this issue if you can. When i remove the circle page indicator app is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

First define your own custom circle page-indicator let it be CirclePageIndicator.cs add this to your project (not activity file)
using Android.Content;

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Util;
using Java.Lang;
using Java.Interop;


namespace MyApplication.Droid.Library
{
    public class CirclePageIndicator : View,PageIndicator
    {
        const int HORIZONTAL = 0;
        const int VERTICAL = 1;
        private float mRadius;
        private Paint mPaintPageFill;
        private Paint mPaintStroke;
        private Paint mPaintFill;
        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        private ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener mListener;
        private int mCurrentPage;
        private int mSnapPage;
        private int mCurrentOffset;
        private int mScrollState;
        private int mPageSize;
        private int mOrientation;
        private bool mCentered;
        private bool mSnap;
        private const int INVALID_POINTER = -1;
        private int mTouchSlop;
        private float mLastMotionX = -1;
        private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER;
        private bool mIsDragging;

        public CirclePageIndicator(Context context) : this(context, null)
        {
        }

        public CirclePageIndicator(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : this(context, attrs, Resource.Attribute.vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle)
        {
        }

        public CirclePageIndicator(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
            //Load defaults from resources
            var res = Resources;
            int defaultPageColor = res.GetColor(Resource.Color.default_circle_indicator_page_color);
            int defaultFillColor = res.GetColor(Resource.Color.default_circle_indicator_fill_color);
            int defaultOrientation = res.GetInteger(Resource.Integer.default_circle_indicator_orientation);
            int defaultStrokeColor = res.GetColor(Resource.Color.default_circle_indicator_stroke_color);
            float defaultStrokeWidth = res.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.default_circle_indicator_stroke_width);
            float defaultRadius = res.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.default_circle_indicator_radius);
            bool defaultCentered = res.GetBoolean(Resource.Boolean.default_circle_indicator_centered);
            bool defaultSnap = res.GetBoolean(Resource.Boolean.default_circle_indicator_snap);

            //Retrieve styles attributes
            var a = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.CirclePageIndicator, defStyle, Resource.Style.Widget_CirclePageIndicator);

            mCentered = a.GetBoolean(Resource.Styleable.CirclePageIndicator_centered, defaultCentered);
            mOrientation = a.GetInt(Resource.Styleable.CirclePageIndicator_orientation, defaultOrientation);
            mPaintPageFill = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
            mPaintPageFill.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
            mPaintPageFill.Color = a.GetColor(Resource.Styleable.CirclePageIndicator_pageColor, defaultPageColor);
            mPaintStroke = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
            mPaintStroke.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
            mPaintStroke.Color = a.GetColor(Resource.Styleable.CirclePageIndicator_strokeColor, defaultStrokeColor);
            mPaintStroke.StrokeWidth = a.GetDimension(Resource.Styleable.CirclePageIndicator_strokeWidth, defaultStrokeWidth);
            mPaintFill = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
            mPaintFill.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
            mPaintFill.Color = a.GetColor(Resource.Styleable.CirclePageIndicator_fillColor, defaultFillColor);
            mRadius = a.GetDimension(Resource.Styleable.CirclePageIndicator_radius, defaultRadius);
            mSnap = a.GetBoolean(Resource.Styleable.CirclePageIndicator_snap, defaultSnap);

            a.Recycle();

            var configuration = ViewConfiguration.Get(context);
            mTouchSlop = ViewConfigurationCompat.GetScaledPagingTouchSlop(configuration);

        }

        public void SetCentered(bool centered)
        {
            mCentered = centered;
            Invalidate();
        }

        public bool IsCentered()
        {
            return mCentered;
        }

        public void SetPageColor(Color pageColor)
        {
            mPaintPageFill.Color = pageColor;
            Invalidate();
        }

        public int GetPageColor()
        {
            return mPaintPageFill.Color;
        }

        public void SetFillColor(Color fillColor)
        {
            mPaintFill.Color = fillColor;
            Invalidate();
        }

        public int GetFillColor()
        {
            return mPaintFill.Color;
        }

        public void setOrientation(int orientation)
        {
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case HORIZONTAL:
                case VERTICAL:
                    mOrientation = orientation;
                    UpdatePageSize();
                    RequestLayout();
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Orientation must be either HORIZONTAL or VERTICAL.");
            }
        }

        public int GetOrientation()
        {
            return mOrientation;
        }

        public void SetStrokeColor(Color strokeColor)
        {
            mPaintStroke.Color = strokeColor;
            Invalidate();
        }

        public int GetStrokeColor()
        {
            return mPaintStroke.Color;
        }

        public void SetStrokeWidth(float strokeWidth)
        {
            mPaintStroke.StrokeWidth = strokeWidth;
            Invalidate();
        }

        public float GetStrokeWidth()
        {
            return mPaintStroke.StrokeWidth;
        }

        public void SetRadius(float radius)
        {
            mRadius = radius;
            Invalidate();
        }

        public float GetRadius()
        {
            return mRadius;
        }

        public void SetSnap(bool snap)
        {
            mSnap = snap;
            Invalidate();
        }

        public bool IsSnap()
        {
            return mSnap;
        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);

            if (mViewPager == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            int count = mViewPager.Adapter.Count;
            if (count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (mCurrentPage >= count)
            {
                SetCurrentItem(count - 1);
                return;
            }

            int longSize;
            int longPaddingBefore;
            int longPaddingAfter;
            int shortPaddingBefore;
            if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL)
            {
                longSize = Width;
                longPaddingBefore = PaddingLeft;
                longPaddingAfter = PaddingRight;
                shortPaddingBefore = PaddingTop;
            }
            else
            {
                longSize = Height;
                longPaddingBefore = PaddingTop;
                longPaddingAfter = PaddingBottom;
                shortPaddingBefore = PaddingLeft;
            }

            float threeRadius = mRadius * 3;
            float shortOffset = shortPaddingBefore + mRadius;
            float longOffset = longPaddingBefore + mRadius;
            if (mCentered)
            {
                longOffset += ((longSize - longPaddingBefore - longPaddingAfter) / 2.0f) - ((count * threeRadius) / 2.0f);
            }

            float dX;
            float dY;

            float pageFillRadius = mRadius;
            if (mPaintStroke.StrokeWidth > 0)
            {
                pageFillRadius -= mPaintStroke.StrokeWidth / 2.0f;
            }

            //Draw stroked circles
            for (int iLoop = 0; iLoop < count; iLoop++)
            {
                float drawLong = longOffset + (iLoop * threeRadius);
                if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL)
                {
                    dX = drawLong;
                    dY = shortOffset;
                }
                else
                {
                    dX = shortOffset;
                    dY = drawLong;
                }
                // Only paint fill if not completely transparent
                if (mPaintPageFill.Alpha > 0)
                {
                    canvas.DrawCircle(dX, dY, pageFillRadius, mPaintPageFill);
                }

                // Only paint stroke if a stroke width was non-zero
                if (pageFillRadius != mRadius)
                {
                    canvas.DrawCircle(dX, dY, mRadius, mPaintStroke);
                }
            }

            //Draw the filled circle according to the current scroll
            float cx = (mSnap ? mSnapPage : mCurrentPage) * threeRadius;
            if (!mSnap && (mPageSize != 0))
            {
                cx += (mCurrentOffset * 1.0f / mPageSize) * threeRadius;
            }
            if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL)
            {
                dX = longOffset + cx;
                dY = shortOffset;
            }
            else
            {
                dX = shortOffset;
                dY = longOffset + cx;
            }
            canvas.DrawCircle(dX, dY, mRadius, mPaintFill);
        }

        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {

            if (base.OnTouchEvent(ev))
            {
                return true;
            }
            if ((mViewPager == null) || (mViewPager.Adapter.Count == 0))
            {
                return false;
            }

            var action = ev.Action;

            switch ((int)action & MotionEventCompat.ActionMask)
            {
                case (int)MotionEventActions.Down:
                    mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.GetPointerId(ev, 0);
                    mLastMotionX = ev.GetX();
                    break;

                case (int)MotionEventActions.Move:
                    {
                        int activePointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.FindPointerIndex(ev, mActivePointerId);
                        float x = MotionEventCompat.GetX(ev, activePointerIndex);
                        float deltaX = x - mLastMotionX;

                        if (!mIsDragging)
                        {
                            if (Java.Lang.Math.Abs(deltaX) > mTouchSlop)
                            {
                                mIsDragging = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if (mIsDragging)
                        {
                            if (!mViewPager.IsFakeDragging)
                            {
                                mViewPager.BeginFakeDrag();
                            }

                            mLastMotionX = x;

                            mViewPager.FakeDragBy(deltaX);
                        }

                        break;
                    }

                case (int)MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                case (int)MotionEventActions.Up:
                    if (!mIsDragging)
                    {
                        int count = mViewPager.Adapter.Count;
                        int width = Width;
                        float halfWidth = width / 2f;
                        float sixthWidth = width / 6f;

                        if ((mCurrentPage > 0) && (ev.GetX() < halfWidth - sixthWidth))
                        {
                            mViewPager.CurrentItem = mCurrentPage - 1;
                            return true;
                        }
                        else if ((mCurrentPage < count - 1) && (ev.GetX() > halfWidth + sixthWidth))
                        {
                            mViewPager.CurrentItem = mCurrentPage + 1;
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    mIsDragging = false;
                    mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER;
                    if (mViewPager.IsFakeDragging)
                        mViewPager.EndFakeDrag();
                    break;

                case MotionEventCompat.ActionPointerDown:
                    {
                        int index = MotionEventCompat.GetActionIndex(ev);
                        float x = MotionEventCompat.GetX(ev, index);
                        mLastMotionX = x;
                        mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.GetPointerId(ev, index);
                        break;
                    }

                case MotionEventCompat.ActionPointerUp:
                    int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.GetActionIndex(ev);
                    int pointerId = MotionEventCompat.GetPointerId(ev, pointerIndex);
                    if (pointerId == mActivePointerId)
                    {
                        int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                        mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.GetPointerId(ev, newPointerIndex);
                    }
                    mLastMotionX = MotionEventCompat.GetX(ev, MotionEventCompat.FindPointerIndex(ev, mActivePointerId));
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public void SetViewPager(ViewPager view)
        {
            if (view.Adapter == null)
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager does not have adapter instance.");
            }
            mViewPager = view;
           mViewPager.SetOnPageChangeListener(this);
            UpdatePageSize();
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void UpdatePageSize()
        {
            if (mViewPager != null)
            {
                mPageSize = (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL) ? mViewPager.Width : mViewPager.Height;
            }
        }

        public void SetViewPager(ViewPager view, int initialPosition)
        {
            SetViewPager(view);
            SetCurrentItem(initialPosition);
        }

        public void SetCurrentItem(int item)
        {
            if (mViewPager == null)
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager has not been bound.");
            }
            mViewPager.CurrentItem = item;
            mCurrentPage = item;
            Invalidate();
        }

        public void NotifyDataSetChanged()
        {
            Invalidate();
        }

        public void OnPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
        {
            mScrollState = state;

            if (mListener != null)
            {
                mListener.OnPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        public void OnPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
        {
            mCurrentPage = position;
            mCurrentOffset = positionOffsetPixels;
            UpdatePageSize();
            Invalidate();

            if (mListener != null)
            {
                mListener.OnPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        public void OnPageSelected(int position)
        {
            if (mSnap || mScrollState == ViewPager.ScrollStateIdle)
            {
                mCurrentPage = position;
                mSnapPage = position;
                Invalidate();
            }

            if (mListener != null)
            {
                mListener.OnPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

        public void SetOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener listener)
        {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        {
            if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL)
            {
                SetMeasuredDimension(MeasureLong(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureShort(heightMeasureSpec));
            }
            else
            {
                SetMeasuredDimension(MeasureShort(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureLong(heightMeasureSpec));
            }
        }

        /**
         * Determines the width of this view
         *
         * @param measureSpec
         *            A measureSpec packed into an int
         * @return The width of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
         */
        private int MeasureLong(int measureSpec)
        {
            int result = 0;
            var specMode = MeasureSpec.GetMode(measureSpec);
            var specSize = MeasureSpec.GetSize(measureSpec);

            if ((specMode == MeasureSpecMode.Exactly) || (mViewPager == null))
            {
                //We were told how big to be
                result = specSize;
            }
            else
            {
                //Calculate the width according the views count
                int count = mViewPager.Adapter.Count;
                result = (int)(PaddingLeft + PaddingRight
                        + (count * 2 * mRadius) + (count - 1) * mRadius + 1);
                //Respect AT_MOST value if that was what is called for by measureSpec
                if (specMode == MeasureSpecMode.AtMost)
                {
                    result = Java.Lang.Math.Min(result, specSize);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        /**
         * Determines the height of this view
         *
         * @param measureSpec
         *            A measureSpec packed into an int
         * @return The height of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
         */
        private int MeasureShort(int measureSpec)
        {
            int result = 0;
            var specMode = MeasureSpec.GetMode(measureSpec);
            var specSize = MeasureSpec.GetSize(measureSpec);

            if (specMode == MeasureSpecMode.Exactly)
            {
                //We were told how big to be
                result = specSize;
            }
            else
            {
                //Measure the height
                result = (int)(2 * mRadius + PaddingTop + PaddingBottom + 1);
                //Respect AT_MOST value if that was what is called for by measureSpec
                if (specMode == MeasureSpecMode.AtMost)
                {
                    result = Java.Lang.Math.Min(result, specSize);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected override void OnRestoreInstanceState(IParcelable state)
        {

            try
            {
                SavedState savedState = (SavedState)state;
                base.OnRestoreInstanceState(savedState.SuperState);
                mCurrentPage = savedState.CurrentPage;
                mSnapPage = savedState.CurrentPage;
            }
            catch
            {
                base.OnRestoreInstanceState(state);
                // Ignore, this needs to support IParcelable...
            }
            RequestLayout();
        }

        protected override IParcelable OnSaveInstanceState()
        {
            var superState = base.OnSaveInstanceState();
            var savedState = new SavedState(superState);
            savedState.CurrentPage = mCurrentPage;
            return savedState;
        }

        public class SavedState : BaseSavedState
        {
            public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

            public SavedState(IParcelable superState) : base(superState)
            {
            }

            private SavedState(Parcel parcel) : base(parcel)
            {
                CurrentPage = parcel.ReadInt();
            }

            public override void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
            {
                base.WriteToParcel(dest, flags);
                dest.WriteInt(CurrentPage);
            }

            [ExportField("CREATOR")]
            static SavedStateCreator InitializeCreator()
            {
                return new SavedStateCreator();
            }

            class SavedStateCreator : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelableCreator
            {
                public Java.Lang.Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
                {
                    return new SavedState(source);
                }

                public Java.Lang.Object[] NewArray(int size)
                {
                    return new SavedState[size];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now add PageIndicator.cs file to your project (not activity file)

```c#
using Android.Support.V4.View;

namespace MyApplication.Droid.Library
{
    public interface PageIndicator : ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener
    {
        /**
         * Bind the indicator to a ViewPager.
         *
         * @param view
         */
        void SetViewPager(ViewPager view);

        /**
         * Bind the indicator to a ViewPager.
         *
         * @param view
         * @param initialPosition
         */
        void SetViewPager(ViewPager view, int initialPosition);

        /**
         * <p>Set the current page of both the ViewPager and indicator.</p>
         *
         * <p>This <strong>must</strong> be used if you need to set the page before
         * the views are drawn on screen (e.g., default start page).</p>
         *
         * @param item
         */
        void SetCurrentItem(int item);

        /**
         * Set a page change listener which will receive forwarded events.
         *
         * @param listener
         */
        void SetOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener listener);

        /**
         * Notify the indicator that the fragment list has changed.
         */
        void NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Now add the following files to your values file:
vpi__styles.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="Widget"></style>

  <style name="Widget.CirclePageIndicator" parent="Widget">
    <item name="centered">@bool/default_circle_indicator_centered</item>
    <item name="fillColor">@color/default_circle_indicator_fill_color</item>
    <item name="pageColor">@color/default_circle_indicator_page_color</item>
    <item name="orientation">@integer/default_circle_indicator_orientation</item>
    <item name="radius">@dimen/default_circle_indicator_radius</item>
    <item name="snap">@bool/default_circle_indicator_snap</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/default_circle_indicator_stroke_color</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">@dimen/default_circle_indicator_stroke_width</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

vpi__defaults.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <bool name="default_circle_indicator_centered">true</bool>
  <color name="default_circle_indicator_fill_color">#FFFFFFFF</color>
  <color name="default_circle_indicator_page_color">#00000000</color>
  <integer name="default_circle_indicator_orientation">0</integer>
  <dimen name="default_circle_indicator_radius">3dp</dimen>
  <bool name="default_circle_indicator_snap">false</bool>
  <color name="default_circle_indicator_stroke_color">#FFDDDDDD</color>
  <dimen name="default_circle_indicator_stroke_width">1dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

vpi__colors.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <color name="vpi__background_holo_dark">#ff000000</color>
  <color name="vpi__background_holo_light">#fff3f3f3</color>
  <color name="vpi__bright_foreground_disabled_holo_dark">#ff4c4c4c</color>
  <color name="vpi__bright_foreground_disabled_holo_light">#ffb2b2b2</color>
</resources>
```

vpi__attrs.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="ViewPagerIndicator">
    <!-- Style of the circle indicator. -->
    <attr name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle" format="reference"/>
  </declare-styleable>
  <declare-styleable name="CirclePageIndicator">
    <!-- Whether or not the indicators should be centered. -->
    <attr name="centered" format="boolean" />
    <!-- Color of the filled circle that represents the current page. -->
    <attr name="fillColor" format="color" />
    <!-- Color of the filled circles that represents pages. -->
    <attr name="pageColor" format="color" />
    <!-- Orientation of the indicator. -->
    <attr name="orientation">
      <enum name="horizontal" value="0" />
      <enum name="vertical" value="1" />
    </attr>
    <!-- Radius of the circles. This is also the spacing between circles. -->
    <attr name="radius" format="dimension" />
    <!-- Whether or not the selected indicator snaps to the circles. -->
    <attr name="snap" format="boolean" />
    <!-- Color of the open circles. -->
    <attr name="strokeColor" format="color" />
    <!-- Width of the stroke used to draw the circles. -->
    <attr name="strokeWidth" format="dimension" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Now add this code to design file.
Here you have to notice that MyApplication.Droid.Library is my name space and CirclePageIndicator is my page indicator file name so replace it with your's

```xml
  <MyApplication.Droid.Library.CirclePageIndicator
      android:id="@+id/indicator"
      android:padding="10dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />
```

now add the following in the activity file.

```c#
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using MyApplication.Droid.Library;
//global
public ViewPager mPager;
public PageIndicator mIndicator;
//in on create 
 var indicator = FindViewById<CirclePageIndicator>(Resource.Id.indicator);
            mIndicator = indicator;
            indicator.SetViewPager(mPager);
            indicator.SetSnap(true);
```

I had solved this from the github

Answer (score 0):

I got it working just like iOS PageControl.

Create the custom class as such:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace myProject.CustomWidgets
{
    public class PageControl : LinearLayout
    {
        #region Properties

        private int _currentPage = 0;

        public int CurrentPage
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentPage;
            }

            set
            {
                _currentPage = value;

                SetCurrentPageIndicator();
            }
        }

        public int Pages = 0;

        public Color PageIndicatorTintColor = ColorHelper.Clear;

        public Color CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor = ColorHelper.Clear;

        private readonly Context context;

        private List<ImageView> ivList = new List<ImageView>();

        private List<Drawable> drawableList = new List<Drawable>();

        private readonly int circleSize = 7;

        #endregion Properties

        #region Constructor

        protected PageControl(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

        public PageControl(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            InitConfig();
        }

        public PageControl(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
            this.context = context;
            InitConfig();
        }

        public PageControl(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
        {
            this.context = context;
            InitConfig();
        }

        public PageControl(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
        {
            this.context = context;
            InitConfig();
        }

        #endregion Constructor

        #region Methods

        private void InitConfig()
        {
            Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {
            base.OnAttachedToWindow();

            Render();
        }

        private void Render()
        {
            // Start with a clean slate
            RemoveAllViews();
            ivList = new List<ImageView>();
            drawableList = new List<Drawable>();

            if (Pages <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Pages; i++)
            {
                var iv = new ImageView(context);

                var size = ConvertionHelper.DensityToPixels(context, circleSize);
                var margin = (int)(size / 2.5);

                var lp = new LayoutParams(size, size);
                lp.SetMargins(margin, 0, margin, 0);

                iv.LayoutParameters = lp;

                /* By default, all drawables instances loaded from the same resource share a common state.
                 * If you modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive the same modification.
                 * Calling this method on a mutable Drawable will have no effect */
                var drawable = ResourcesHelper.GetDrawable(context, Resource.Drawable.ic_circle_separator).Mutate();
                drawable.SetColorFilter(PageIndicatorTintColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);

                iv.SetImageDrawable(drawable);

                drawableList.Add(drawable);

                ivList.Add(iv);

                AddView(iv);
            }

            // Initial current page indicator set-up
            SetCurrentPageIndicator();
        }

        private void SetCurrentPageIndicator()
        {
            if (ivList.Count == 0 || drawableList.Count == 0 || ivList.Count != drawableList.Count ||
                CurrentPage < 0 || CurrentPage >= ivList.Count)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Reset all colors
            for (int i = 0; i < ivList.Count; i++)
            {
                drawableList[i].SetColorFilter(PageIndicatorTintColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
                ivList[i].SetImageDrawable(drawableList[i]);
            }

            // Change color of current page indicator
            drawableList[CurrentPage].SetColorFilter(CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
            ivList[CurrentPage].SetImageDrawable(drawableList[CurrentPage]);
        }

        #endregion Methods
    }
}
```

Then use on your xml file such as:

```
<myProject.PageControl
        android:id="@+id/pagecontrol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Then on your activity you would have:

```
var pagecontrol = FindViewById<PageControl>(Resource.Id.pagecontrol);
pagecontrol.PageIndicatorTintColor = ColorHelper.PositiveBlue;
pagecontrol.CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor = ColorHelper.Orange;
pagecontrol.CurrentPage = 0;
pagecontrol.Pages = 3;
```