# Why is my project working fine when released or debugged in one system and not working in another system?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Currently I am working in a Xamarin native project which is well developed and in between when we introduced the image view with auto scroll with dot indicators the problem arrived.
The actual problem is when we release or debug from one system only the app is working fine or else if we do that from another system the app is unexpectedly stopped, if the testing phone is connected to the system and if that is in debug state it is working when we remove it from debug it is not working correctly.
I don't know the reason why it is happening.
Initially I thought that there is a problem with the SDK versions JDK Versions and all, I checked by almost equalizing the SDK, JDK and Xamarin versions but unable to detect the problem and correct it for reference of what we added into the project please refer the following links.

[How to implement ViewPagers with Dot Sliders in Xamarin.Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43464142/how-to-implement-viewpagers-with-dot-sliders-in-xamarin-android)

[How to Set auto sliders in pageviewers in xamarin.android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43534476/how-to-set-auto-sliders-in-pageviewers-in-xamarin-android)

I am unable to detect the actual problem causing the problem can any one please let me know the solution of the problem.

Comment: Have you posted a ticket with Xamarin support with logs and specs from the two systems?

Comment: No, I did not. Can you please guide me how to do that or any links...

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You get this type of issue then follow the steps below
1. Try to make a exact copy of SDk from the working system and copy in some other drive and map the reference in VS.

2.If that does not work then also, make sure all the versions in systems are equal.

If then also it does not work it is an internal issue so uninstall the complete VS and make a fresh installation this should work at any cost.